# How to present icons in neat responsive rows

Tags: html, css

I'm making a control panel display, but this is what happens the display is not flat

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Aplication</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <div class="col-sm-2" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Instagram_icon.png/2048px-Instagram_icon.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Instagram Lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Facebook_logo_%28square%29.png/800px-Facebook_logo_%28square%29.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Facebook lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">
          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6159/6159318.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Ip Lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://ifadtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/dns-icon.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>DNS LOOKUP</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 aplication-items" align="center">
        <div class="aplication-items">

          <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: here is screenshot]

and i want all the item is responsive and flat like this

```
item item item item
item item item item
```

not

```
item item item item
item
item item item
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS and frameworks like bootstrap if you use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex-box` to do that .

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid-item {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  flex: 1 1 250px;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background: #40424a;
  color: #e4e4e8;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 2.125em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.wrapper p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #c4c4c8;
}

.grid-item figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.grid-item figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Instagram_icon.png/2048px-Instagram_icon.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Instagram Lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Facebook_logo_%28square%29.png/800px-Facebook_logo_%28square%29.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Facebook lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/6159/6159318.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Ip Lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://ifadtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/dns-icon.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>DNS LOOKUP</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
         <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
         <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
      <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
       <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <figure>
      <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5526/5526522.png" alt="" srcset="" width="50%" style="max-width: 90px;">
          <p>Dasis lookup</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```